# Keyboard connected via USB OTG writes wrong characters

Tags: keyboard, usb-on-the-go

I have keyboard+mouse combo connected via USB A -> USB C reduction. Mouse works as expected, but keyboard writes wrong characters (it starts in second line see below).

I tried two different USB combos (from different manufacturer - Logi(tech), Yenkee) and both produce same result.

It's Asus stock Android 11, system language is English, SW keyboard is SwiftKey (QWERTZ, EN+CZ), also I use Bluetooth keyboard Logitech K840 which works as expected.

<kbd>`</kbd>  <kbd>1</kbd>  <kbd>2</kbd>  <kbd>3</kbd>  <kbd>4</kbd>  <kbd>5</kbd>  <kbd>6</kbd>  <kbd>7</kbd>  <kbd>8</kbd>  <kbd>9</kbd>  <kbd>0</kbd>  <kbd>-</kbd>  <kbd>=</kbd>

`ˋ1234567890-=`

<kbd>Q</kbd>  <kbd>W</kbd>  <kbd>E</kbd>  <kbd>R</kbd>  <kbd>T</kbd>  <kbd>Y</kbd>  <kbd>U</kbd>  <kbd>I</kbd>  <kbd>O</kbd>  <kbd>P</kbd>  <kbd>[</kbd>  <kbd>]</kbd>

`` qw`rty¨ˆop[] ``

<kbd>A</kbd>  <kbd>S</kbd>  <kbd>D</kbd>  <kbd>F</kbd>  <kbd>G</kbd>  <kbd>H</kbd>  <kbd>J</kbd>  <kbd>K</kbd>  <kbd>L</kbd>  <kbd>;</kbd>  <kbd>'</kbd>

`aßdfghjkl;'`

<kbd>Z</kbd>  <kbd>X</kbd>  <kbd>C</kbd>  <kbd>V</kbd>  <kbd>B</kbd>  <kbd>N</kbd>  <kbd>M</kbd>  <kbd>,</kbd>  <kbd>.</kbd>  <kbd>/</kbd>

`zxçvb˜m,./`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is no layout selected for physical keyboard - it's set for each keyboard separately in `Settings` > `System` > `Languages & input` > `Physical keyboard` > `[Select your keyboard]` > `[Select a layout from a list]`